# making menu appear onclick on mobile reponsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On one of our sites we are having a problem with responsive design. we would like to make the "sub menus" in the main navigation (the sub list items) display none as and appear when you click on..... "menu" for example. The only problem is that if you click on menu it takes you to the menu page because it is a link...

Here is the website

http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/

```
<ul id="mobilenav"><li id="back"><a href="#top" class="menutop">Hide Navigation</a>  </li><li id="menu-item-1549" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-1546 current_page_item menu-item-1549"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/menu/">Menu</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-88" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-88"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/wine-beer-cocktails/">Wine, Beer &amp; Cocktails</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-87" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-87"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/appetizers/">Appetizers</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-86" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-86"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/soups/">Soups</a>  </li>
<li id="menu-item-84" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-84"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/wraps-sandwiches/">Sandwiches</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-85" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-85"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/burgers-dogs/">Burgers &amp; Dogs</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-82" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-82"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/saladandfishplates/">Salads &amp; Smoked Fish</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-83" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-83"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/entrees/">Entrees</a>  </li>
<li id="menu-item-1631" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1631"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/dessert/">Dessert</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-81" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-81"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/247-breakfast/">24/7 Breakfast</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1070" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1070"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/daily-specials/">Daily Specials</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1629" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1629"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/from-the-delicatessen/">Delicatessen</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1630" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1630"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/kids/">Kids</a>        </li>
<li id="menu-item-2357" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-2357"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/StageDeliMenu_Dec2012.pdf">PDF Menu</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-898" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-898"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/catering-2/">Catering</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-313" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-313"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/appetizer-platters/">Appetizers</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-311" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-311"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/lunch-trays/">Trays</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-2239" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2239"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/box-lunches/">Box Lunches</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-310" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-310"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/hot-entrees/">Entrees</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-312" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-312"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/fruit-dessert/">Desserts</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1608" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1608"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/family-style-dining/">Family Style Dining</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1610" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1610"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/overnight-deli-to-you/">Deli To You</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1611" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1611"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/delivery/">Delivery</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-2356" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-2356"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/StageDeli_Catering.pdf">PDF Catering Menu</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/history/">About Us</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-1563" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1563"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/food/">Food</a>   </li>
<li id="menu-item-1562" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1562"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/bread/">Bread</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1561" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1561"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/history-2/">History</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1560" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1560"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/press/">Press</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1559" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1559"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/bios/">Bios</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-2165" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2165"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/mavens-guide/">Mavens Guide</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-2537" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2537"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/events/">Calendar</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1558" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1558"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li id="menu-item-1548" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1548"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/connections/">Community</a>
 <ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-1574" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1574"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/supporting-our-community/">Supporting</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1573" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1573"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/feeding-our-community/">Feeding</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1572" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1572"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/connecting-our-community/">Connecting</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1571" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1571"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/optimist-club/">Optimist</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li id="menu-item-1538" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1538"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/locations/">Hours &amp; Location</a>
 <ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-2199" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2199"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/stage-west-bloomfield/">Stage W. Bloomfield</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1565" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1565"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/naples-stage-62/">Stage 62 Naples</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1564" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1564"><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/stage/somerset-stage-deli/">Stage Deli Somerset</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The HTML is so messy. Please make a fiddle from it and post a link here.

Comment: Why do you have two separate navigation menus?  They look like they have the same content in them.

Answer (score 0):

The mobile browser will generate touch events, so in your code, where there is an `onmouseover` handler also add `ontouchend`, so with jQuery this:

```
$('SELECTOR').on('mouseover', function () {
    // your code to unfold the menu
});
```

becomes this:

```
$('SELECTOR').on('mouseover touchend', function () {
    // your code to unfold the menu
});
```